# php/sql : don't echo show data correctly

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem with my php and sql code. I trying to make code that when i enter some data that related with the database, the output should show 'zero' if the row user_designid equal to 0 and if vice versa it will show 'one'.
but the problem is both of output only show the first anwser ('zero').

Php file (co.php is my config)

```
 <?php
 require "co.php";
 $link = mysqli_connect($h,$u,$p,$db);

 if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
echo "Connected successfully";

$q = "select * from tab_ss_user where User_name ='".$_POST['name']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$q);


if($result){
echo "<table border='1' >
<tr>
<td align=center> <b>user Id No</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Name</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Password</b></td>
<td align=center><b>responsibility</b></td></td>";

while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{   
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align=center><option>$data[0]</option></td>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[1]</td>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[2]</td>";

    //this is the problem
if($data['User_DesignID'] == 0 ){
      echo "<td align=center> zero </td>";
 }
else{
      echo "<td align=center> one </td>";
 }


   echo "</tr>";
 }
   echo "</table>";
 }

  else{
   echo ' Failed';
 }
 ?>
```

that all thank you.

Comment: Any error in the above code execution?

Comment: Try using `===` instead of `==`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp

Comment: Inside `while` add this `print_r($data); die;`. And provide the output.

Comment: where you get "$conn" in your code. Use "$link"

Comment: @MayankPandeyz no error just the output for if($data) not properly function

Comment: @SardonicSaviour still same. but the answer change from only taking 'zero' to only using 'one'

Comment: @KinshukLahiri i dont understant, you mean in while(____) or after {

Comment: @A.ANoman ooh, typo over there sorry. but still work even though it not the same. (still not fixing the problem)

Comment: @Nexz After `{`

Comment: @KinshukLahiri do you mean like this? while(____)( print_r($data);die; echo "-------";}

Comment: @Nexz Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not referencing the field correctly See [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_row.asp)

When using mysqli_fetch_row, the result is an associative array so `$data['User_DesignID']` will not be referenced correctly.

Comment: that's correct. i should using the column number instead of column name.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure your column  name is "User_DesignID"
if($data['User_DesignID'] == 0 ){

Comment: you can use mysql_fetch_assoc() for using column name

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks to Jeffrey idea, I have found an answer (please refer to Jeffrey's answer on this page).

And also if you want to use column name instead please use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of row.